# How can I backup several windows digital licenses without using a Microsoft account?

Tags: windows, license

I have several computers with Windows 10 Pro licenses. I use a couple actively and the rest I turn on every three or four months, update, backup, then turn off again. Using my Microsoft account to register each of the digital licenses will not work for me.

I used the command "slmgr /dti" to display an "Installation ID". If I do that command on each machine and save the numbers, then if one of the machines no longer works, can I always use the number saved for that machine on a new machine? Can I unregister a machine and sell the number? I have no OEM licenses and have no issues with any of the licenses.

From what I read, if I have an "Installation ID" and call the Microsoft phone number, I will obtain a product key of the xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx variety I can use to activate a new windows installation. If I wanted to sell a license that may work, too. I may do that and get rid of some machines.

I would like an answer from someone who has worked with this a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> I have several computers with Windows 10 Pro licenses. I use a couple actively and the rest I turn on every three or four months, update, backup, then turn off again. Using my Microsoft account to register each of the digital licenses will not work for me.

It’s unnecessary to link your Microsoft Account to a local account on each machine.  Windows 10 uses a digital entitlement system.  Regardless if you link the machine to a Microsoft Account, Windows 10 will automatically activate, once its previously been installed on that machine.  This is true for both Retail and OEM licenses.

> I used the command "slmgr /dti" to display an "Installation ID". If I do that command on each machine and save the numbers, then if one of the machines no longer works, can I always use the number saved for that machine on a new machine?

You can only transfer Retail Windows 10 licenses to new machines.  The Installation ID isn’t enough information to reinstall Windows 10.  If you want to literally have the license key required to activate Windows 10, [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus), will provide that information.  However, it’s unnecessary to know that information, once installed on a system the license key isn’t required to activate Windows 10

> Can I unregister a machine and sell the number?

You are allowed to sell Retail licenses to another individual.  However, there isn’t a huge market for used licenses, to much risk on the part of the buyer.

> From what I read, if I have an "Installation ID" and call the Microsoft phone number, I will obtain a product key of the xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx variety I can use to activate a new windows installation.

What you have read isn’t entirely accurate.  You still have to input the license key in order to activate your installation by phone.  The process is a simple challenge response system.  You provide the challenge code and Microsoft provides the response and after a reboot your system is activated.

> If I wanted to sell a license that may work, too. I may do that and get rid of some machines.

Realistically only Retail Windows licenses can be sold to a third-party.  OEM licenses would simply refuse to activate on new hardware.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if it does, you can transfer your license to new machines, provided you have a Retail license